# Modular arithmetic - re-arranging equation to get outcome

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it possible for me to show

$a=7\beta-7\alpha,\ b=3\alpha-2\beta$

If I know that

$\alpha=4a+b,\ \beta=19a+b$

in $mod\ 26$

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm new to modular arithmetic, so still figuring things out.

Comment: Future readers, answer is here: https://ibb.co/54Zk0TP

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\alpha=4a+b$ and $\beta=19a+b$, then you can show what you want as follows:

$\beta-\alpha=(19a+b)-(4a+b)=15a$, so $7\beta-7\alpha=7\times15a=105a=4\times26a+a\equiv a \bmod 26,$

and $3\alpha-2\beta=3(4a+b)-2(19a+b)=(12a+3b)-(38a+2b)=-26a+b\equiv b\bmod 26$.

---

You could also say $\pmatrix{\alpha\\\beta}=\pmatrix{4&&1\\19&&1}\pmatrix{a\\b}$, so $\pmatrix{a\\b}=\pmatrix{4&&1\\19&&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{\alpha\\\beta}$,

and $\pmatrix{4&&1\\19&&1}^{-1}\equiv {\pmatrix{1&&-1\\7&&4}}(15)^{-1}\equiv{\pmatrix{1&&-1\\7&&4}}(19)={\pmatrix{-7&&7\\3&&-2}}$.

Comment: Could you explain this to me like I'm five? thanks. For a start, how did you get $\beta$ and $\alpha$ together?

Comment: Also, where did you get the $15a$ from?

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because you are using the first part from the beginning. The question is asking if it is possible to use the second part to get the first part.

Comment: I will edit to include more details

Answer (score 0):

$4a + b \equiv \alpha \pmod{26}$

$19a + b\equiv \beta \pmod{26}$ so subtract

$15a \equiv \beta - \alpha \pmod{26}$ multiply but $7$

$105a \equiv 7(\beta -\alpha)\pmod {26}$

But $105a \equiv (4*26+1)a\equiv a \pmod {26}$ so $a \equiv 7\beta - 7\alpha$.

The other is not so straightforward byt the same idea.

$19(4a + b) \equiv 19\alpha\pmod{26}$

$4(19a + b) \equiv 4\beta\pmod{26}$ so subtract

$15b \equiv 19\alpha - 4\beta\pmod{26}$.  Multiply by $7$

$7*15b \equiv 7*19\alpha - 7*4\beta \pmod{26}$

$105 b \equiv 133\alpha - 28\beta \pmod {26}$

$(4*26 + 1)b \equiv (5*26+3)\alpha - (26+2)\beta\pmod {26}$

$b \equiv 3\alpha - 2\beta\pmod {26}$.

=====

Alternatively if $\alpha \equiv 4a+b$ and $\beta \equiv 19a + b$ then

$7\beta - 7\alpha \equiv 7(19a + b)-7(4a+b)\equiv$

$133a -28a\equiv$

$105a\equiv a$.

And $3\alpha -  2\beta \equiv 3(4a+b)-2(19a+b)\equiv$

$(12a + 3b)-(38a +2b) \equiv$

$-26a + b\equiv b$.

Actually, I think maybe we were *supposed* to do it the second way rather than the first.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 7 in line 3?

Comment: Because I have $\beta -\alpha$ but  I want $7\beta - 7\alpha$

Comment: Thank you for the help, your answer did help, but it isn't as clear as I'd like it to be, I have requested for this question to be opened again so I can post my own answer. I have up-voted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure I'd say the question are the same but.... solving modular equations is a basic subject that once you learn it always applies.  All aritmetic operations (*except* division and roots) distribute in modular arithmetic so you *do* solve the same way you would normally.

Comment: Doesn't look like this question will be re-opened, anyway, here is what I was looking for: https://ibb.co/54Zk0TP